# Estimating Pi by Throwing Bread

Tags: probability, circles, approximation, estimation, pi

I remember hearing about a story in which an Italian King (hundreds of years ago) drew a circle and randomly threw bread behind his shoulder, and calculated the percent of bread that landed inside the circle vs outside the circle. Supposedly this was an early attempt to estimation pi.

I tried look for this story online, and the closest thing I could find was "Buffon's Needle", which pi can be estimated by randomly dropping needles on to an a rectangular surface marked with rectangular tiles:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle_problem

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BuffonsNeedleProblem.html

Does anyone have a reference for the "Bread throwing story"?

Thanks!

Comment: This is probably a fake story. You could try to source its origin, but this has never in human history been a good way to estimate pi.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will try to keep looking and keep this in mind!

Comment: This is essentially the Monte Carlo method so you might start there

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This sounds correct! I will try to look in to this! Thanks!

Comment: To echo the other responses: it's hard to imagine a person who would (1) have the sophistication to be able to use a method like this to estimate $\pi$, **and** (2) not be aware of the monumental error of estimation that would be induced from a physical process like this. I would be very, very surprised if anyone has ever done this as an earnest method to estimate $\pi$. (As a novelty, though? I'm sure some bored MIT student has done it or something.)